# Unable to retrieve a facebook token only on initial sign up and external login confirmation in .net

Tags: .net, facebook

I've got my .net app posting a photo to facebook. It works fine on every subsequent use after the initial login and registration. The user can't register or login any other way other than logging in with facebook.

On all the logins (except the very first) the user logs in and the externallogincallback method gets called and then the methods StoreFacebookAuthToken and SignInAsync are called and the token gets stored and this works.

But on the first login and registration the user clicks facebook login -> the user enters an email address to associate with the fb account and then ExternalLoginConfirmation is called.

To get the facebook token on initial login I put StoreFacebookAuthToken and SignInAsync in ExternalLoginConfirmation but then i can't post a photo - I'm assuming the access token doesn't get stored but I can't figure out exactly why.

I haven't posted all the code b/c it's pretty long but any ideas would be great. Thx.

**Startup.auth.cs**

```
var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
  AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Facebook_AppId"],
  AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Facebook_AppSecret"],

 SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
 SendAppSecretProof = true
 };
```

**ExternalLoginCallBack**

```
    public ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)    
    {
    case SignInStatus.Success:
    var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);

    if (user != null)
    {
      await StoreFacebookAuthToken(user);
      await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);                               
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Upload", "Home");

    }
    }
```

**External LoginConfirmation**

```
public ExternalLoginConfirmation

    {

     if (result.Succeeded)
    {
       result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
       if (result.Succeeded)
      {
       // await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
          await StoreFacebookAuthToken(user);
          await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

          return RedirectToAction("Upload", "Home");                 
      }
     }
```

Comment: I sorted this out.

Comment: do you mind posting the solution here as an answer? this can help other devs

Comment: added an update to the original post

Comment: can you answer your original post? it will be cleaner.

Comment: I don't have the exact answer actually. To be honest i'm not even sure how it let me post photos at all because i have never been able to get the fb access token from the controller. And that is something i'm still struggling with. I can't figure out how to get the fb token from the claim: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605220/is-the-appropriate-context-to-get-the-fb-access-token-httpcontext-getowincontext Cheers